# Applying transformation on html string inside a json response of ajax in moovweb

Tags: moovweb

Hi I am new on moovweb and I got stuck on a requirement to apply transformation logic on ajax response which is coming in a json format containing html, which I have to add on my page.

A sample response

```
{
  "success":true,
  "html" :"<div>This can be a big html data</div>"
}
```

SO basically, I need to apply transformation on that html string. I gone through docs but I did't got anything to handle this kind of scenario.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then there are several steps that you need to take in order to solve this issue.

1. Open your Moovweb project using Google Chrome, right click your mouse and choose Inspect Element which will open your Chrome Dev Tools.
2. Choose the Network Tab at the top of your Chrome Dev Tools which will be the second tab from the left.
3. Trigger the ajax call on your site and you will see under the Network Tab the response URL of the ajax call. Most of the time it will be in a format like www.yoursite.com/ajax/rest_of_url
4. Once you have found the ajax response URL then open your main.ts file in your tritium script and insert the following code if your response URL is similar to the format provided above:

   ```
   match($path){
     with(/ajax/){ #or wherever the site files for the ajax response are contained
     log("--> importing ajax.ts")
     @import ajax.ts
     }
   }
   ```
5. Now created a file in for your tritium code called ajax.ts. The file will be in the same location as your html.ts and main.ts files. With the code applied above to your main.ts, every time a URL is called that contains /ajax/ then the ajax.ts file will be applied.
6. Now you can open your new ajax.ts file that you created and start applying your tritium functions to transform the json format containing html to way you need it.